Web scraping with Python BeautifulSoup in Spyder IDE
I'm trying to scrape the table from the following url in Spyder IDE. Following's my code so far.  I inspected the hteml code to figure out the table class and any th, tr, td, tags. But extracting the headers and row data does not work. It concatenates the rows, so the first entry is row 1+ all the rows, row 2 + all the rows. I don't know how to split the rows. Looking the html tags don't help. I'm new to programming and need all the guidance. Also need to get this into a csv file.
url = 'https://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/hurdat/International_Hurricanes.html'
I'm expecting data in the table on the website to be in a csv file.
import os
print(os.getcwd())



import pandas as pd
import requests  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import csv  



url = 'https://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/hurdat/International_Hurricanes.html'
response = requests.get(url)  
html_content = response.text  
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')  


table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'content'})
data = table.find_all('tr')


headers = []
for header in data[2].find_all('td'): 
    header_lines = header.text.strip().split('\r\n')

print(headers)


data = []
for row in rows.find_all('tr')[3:]:`find data after 3rd row`
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [col.get_text(strip=True) for col in cols]
if cols:
    data.append(cols)


As mentioned checkout an alternative parser that handles the HTML correct -> https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser
import requests  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
import csv


url = 'https://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/hurdat/International_Hurricanes.html'
response = requests.get(url)  
html_content = response.text  
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')  

data = soup.select('#tdcontent tr:not(:has(td[colspan]))')

with open('output.csv', mode='w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    #header
    writer.writerow([e.get_text(strip=True) for e in data[0].select('td')])

    #content
    writer.writerows([list(e.stripped_strings) for e in data[1:]])

Just in addition and because you import pandas, there is an approach to read the table directly into a dataframe with pandas.read_html():
import pandas as pd

#read the table, set header to specific row and remove empty at all rows and columns
df = pd.read_html('https://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/hurdat/International_Hurricanes.html', header=1)[2].dropna(how='all', axis=1).dropna(how='all', axis=0)
#filter only rows that do not contain a 's' in the date column
df[~df.iloc[:, 0].astype(str).str.contains('s')]

Output:




#
Date
Time
Latitude
Longitude
Max Winds (kt)
SS HWS
Central Pressure (mb)
Landfall Country
Storm Names




1
4
9/12/1946
2300Z
25.9N
77.3W
65
1
---
Bahamas
---


2
6
10/7/1946
0400Z
22.2N
83.9W
80
1
977
Cuba
---


3
1
8/15/1947
1000Z
21.7N
97.5W
95
2
---
Mexico
---


4
4
9/16/1947
1900Z
26.7N
77.1W
105
3
954
Bahamas
---


5
8
9/20/1948
2200Z
22.3N
82.1W
110
3
---
Cuba
"El Huracan de Matanzas"


...












248
09
09/27/2022
0830Z
22.2N
83.7W
110
3
947
Cuba
Ian


249
13
10/09/2022
0715Z
12.4N
83.6W
75
1
982
Nicaragua
Julia


250
17
11/09/2022
2300Z
26.6N
78.2W
65
1
980
Bahamas
Nicole


251
20
10/22/2023
0115Z
17.6N
61.8W
80
1
987
Barbuda
Tammy




This answer right here, this guy web scrapes. I am a software and automation developer and this is how I would do it.

the document is written in html5, the parser you're using is too strict for html5 unclosed tags (the tds are not closed). use html5lib instead
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/hurdat/International_Hurricanes.html'
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html5lib')


table = soup.select_one('table table')
rows = table.find_all('tr')


headers = [header.text.strip() for header in rows[2].find_all('td')]
print(headers)

output
['#', 'Date', 'Time', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Max  Winds (kt)', 'SS  HWS', 'Central  Pressure  (mb)', 'Landfall  Country', 'Storm  Names']


Changing the parser didn't make a difference. Is there any place I can learn about the parser? I asked my student assistant who mentioned the data[2] is not properly formatted. I have to somehow parse the string, then retrieve each header.

ok added full code. it didn't work with html.parser, and was indeed concatenating the data. the headrow is properly formatted, that's valid html5 code. but you need the right parser

Thank you! I ran it too, it works after changing the parser. Though I want to append the result in a list. But it comes up empty. headers = []
for header in rows[2].find_all('td'):
header.append(header.text.strip())

you forgot an s: headers.append(header.text.strip())

Welp! It introduces duplicate values and a new line. Output(partial) of print(headers)
['#\n##\n##\n##\n#', 'Date\nDateDate\nDate', 'Time \nTimeTime \nTime', 'Latitude \nLatitudeLatitude \nLatitude', 'Longitude \nLongitudeLongitude \nLongitude',

i've tested it, edited my answer with code and output two hours ago and it works fine for me. i don't understand your result, sorry

Thank you. I restarted the kernel and it worked. It helped in finishing my project in time. Posting what I used, if someone else needs it.  # Extract table headers. There no 'th' tag - headers are on the 3rd row in the 'tr' tag
headers = []
for header in rows[2].find_all('td'):
s: headers.append(header.text.strip())
Extract data rows from the 4th row onwards in the table
data = []
for row in rows[3:]:
cells = row.find_all('td')
row_data = [cell.text.strip() for cell in cells]
data.append(row_data)
